# Push numbers to Array on click without using global Scope

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know that the below is perfectly viable:

```
var numberArray = [];

function addNumber(number) {
  numberArray.push(number);
}
```

and then:

```
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="addNum(10);">
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="addNum(990);">
...
```

But is it possible, for a better code, to have both my array and my action on the same function, and then trigger it on a click event, thus populating my array? Asking because, doing this:

```
function addNumber(number) {
  var numberArray = [];
  numberArray.push(number);
}
```

Does not increase the array values.

I know that inline click events is considerate a bad practice nowadays, but it's for learning purposes. All other answers here reference the array as a global scope, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

**Edit:** Ok if the above is not possible, any answer avoiding the global scope usage is valid.

Comment: Wrap all the code in an IIFE, or create an object, which has `addNumber` as a method, and `numberArray` as a property. To utilize one of these, you need to use `addEventListener` to attach events.

Comment: @Teemu: And then add the click handler in JavaScript since `addNumber` will no longer be global.

Comment: `window.addNumber = function...` inside the IIFE

Comment: @taguenizy Instead of this, using the standard `addEventListener` is a much better alternative.

Comment: when the array is declared in the function its scope is confined to that function.

Comment: Because for some reason `addNumber` being global too, doesn't seem to bother you, one more alternative comes into mind. Functions are also objects, you could add `numberArray` as a property to `addNumber`. Then refer it in `addNumber` (or anywhere) like so: `addNumber.numberArray.push(...)`. This way you can even keep the inline listeners.

Comment: @Teemu it doesn't seem to work. Could you pls elaborate an answer?

Comment: You mean using function as an object? Works fine at [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mwh5moLf/2/). Notice, that in your example the inline handlers call `addNum`, when the actual function name is `addNumber`. This method is basically used by some libraries, e.g. jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [Self-Invoking Function](https://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/javascript-self-invoking-functions/), for creating a local scope, then you can add eventListeners instead using `onclick` directive.

```
(function () {
   var numberArray = [];

   function addNumber() {
       var child = this;
       var number = parseInt(child.getAttribute('data-number'), 10);

       numberArray.push(number);
       console.log(numberArray);
   }

   var _elms = document.getElementsByClassName('add-number-input');

   for (var i = 0; i < _elms.length; i++)
       _elms[i].addEventListener('click', addNumber);
})();
```

Add to a class `.add-number-input` to your inputs:

```
<input class="add-number-input" data-number="10" ...>
<input class="add-number-input" data-number="990" ...>
```

Now both your array and your function isn't on global scope.

http://codepen.io/rdsedmundo/pen/EgKGXK

Comment: You should add the "radix" to `parseInt`:  `parseInt('', 10);`

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved using self-invoking function. By this the `numberArray` will be in that function's scope and the method `addNumber` will be exposed as global.

```
(function(){
    var numberArray = [];
    window.addNumber = function(number) {
        numberArray.push(number);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there isn't- at least not one that doesn't defeat your aim of writing better code. Declaring numberArray in addNum() means it is created, initialized and destroyed each time the function is called. I advise that you use the global scope option. However, if you MUST use the options afforded by the other answers because of some program requirements, please do so.

Comment: The other answers are aiming towards better practices, especially Edmundo's.